# Magnet power up Like subway surfers does not work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to make a Magnet power up like subway surfer. My game is a endless runner game. When the runner collide with the magnet, the coins attracting towards the player. But it is not working. After runner collide with the magnet and after that every time he collide with the coin below error keep coming.

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
> Coin.OnTriggerEnter (UnityEngine.Collider other) (at Assets/Scripts/Coin.cs:37)

any one can help me?

Magnet Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Magnet : MonoBehaviour
{
// Start is called before the first frame update
 public GameObject coinDetectorObj;

public static bool iscoinDetectorObj;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

    coinDetectorObj = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("coin detector");
    coinDetectorObj.SetActive(false);
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        StartCoroutine(ActivateCoin());
        Destroy(transform.GetChild(0).gameObject);
        
    }
}

IEnumerator ActivateCoin()
{
    coinDetectorObj.SetActive(true);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    coinDetectorObj.SetActive(false);
}
    }
```

Coin Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Coin : MonoBehaviour
{

public Transform playerTransform;
public float moveSpeed = 17f;

CoinMove coinMoveScript;

void Start()
{
    playerTransform = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
    coinMoveScript = gameObject.GetComponent<CoinMove>();
}

void Update()
{
    transform.Rotate(130 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().PlaySound("PickUpCoin");
        PlayerManager.numberOfCoins += 1;
        Destroy(gameObject);

    }

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "coin detector")
    {
        coinMoveScript.enabled = true;

    }
}

}
```

CoinMove Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CoinMove : MonoBehaviour
{
Coin coinScript;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    coinScript = gameObject.GetComponent<Coin>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, coinScript.playerTransform.position,
        coinScript.moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        //Add count or give points etc etc.
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Which line specifically is line 37? I guess you need to check that other.gameObject is not null before trying to read other.gameObject.tag. If Unity can pass in other == null then you'll need to check for that too.

Comment: And it might be safest to check if other.tag != null before comparing it against another string, but I can't remember just now if that's OK or not.

Comment: @rup that shouldn't do anything, as the tag should always be atleast untagged

Comment: @Rup here is the line 37   "  coinMoveScript.enabled = true; "

Comment: Great, thanks. Then your line in Start() `coinMoveScript = gameObject.GetComponent<CoinMove>();` either didn't find the CoinMove or hasn't been run. I'd guess it didn't find the CoinMove.

Comment: @Rup I think same. What could be the reason?

Comment: I don't know Unity well enough sorry. I'd hope all the objects are created before running Start. Is CoinMove something you're adding after the Magnet was set up?

Comment: @Rup No. CoinMove added lastly. Thank you for your attempt

Comment: OK, then you might want to do something like `if (coinMoveScript == null) coinMoveScript = gameObject.GetComponent<CoinMove>();` in OnTriggerEnter before you try and use coinMoveScript, but you should still check that coinMoveScript != null before setting properties on it in case it still isn't found. Or there may be a Unity way of CoinMove notifying other objects that it now exists, rather than testing for it at the point of use, but I don't know what's possible / best practice in Unity.